# How to deal with server.handleUpgrade() was called more than once in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, node-modules

I am running a nodejs application which runs great the first time I use it but when I refresh and enter the new data Node crashes and gives me this. The error looks like this :

```
/www/wwwroot/domain.to/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:267
      throw new Error(
      ^
Error: server.handleUpgrade() was called more than once with the same socket, possibly due to a misconfiguration
    at WebSocketServer.completeUpgrade (/www/wwwroot/domain.to/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:267:13)
    at WebSocketServer.handleUpgrade (/www/wwwroot/domain.to/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:245:10)
    at Server.upgrade (/www/wwwroot/tehran.us.to/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:89:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at onParserExecuteCommon (_http_server.js:646:14)
    at onParserExecute (_http_server.js:587:3)
```

The code on the server looks like this for express :

```
const app = express();
const options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem')
};
const server = https.createServer(options, app)

server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + 3000);
});
```

I also use Websocket on the same end point and the code looks like this :

```
const wss = new Websocket.Server({ server })
    console.log(url)
    wss.on('connection', ws => {
        console.log('user is connected to the server #mainpage')
```

I don't know how to go around it as the application seems to not create a new instance of the application for a new refresh.

How can I deal with this and make my app running continuously?

Comment: facing the same issue i am using socket.io

Answer (score 16):

This is because you have already created the server using `express` and the `handleUpgrade` method is called inside `express`, so you need to inform your `WebSocket` server to ignore the server initiating part and continue with the existing resource as giving the options as `{ noServer: true }`

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });

server.on('upgrade', function (request, socket, head) {
  wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function (ws) {
     wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, In My project I was using express-monitor which was also using socket.io hence leading the server to handle the upgrade for ws connection request as well as socket.io initialization.

Removing express-monitor solved the issue